# mod_wsgi loading python script from wrong Pyramid app directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache2, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I have two apps with nearly identical code base (same functionality, just different branding) that I am trying to do virtual hosting with using mod_wsgi and apache.

the virtual host settings for both apps (in two separate files) are identical (with the exception of paths of course)

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/ubuntu/BASELINE

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName appA.com
    ServerAlias www.appA.com
    ServerAdmin admin@appA.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA
    ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/error.log
    CustomLog /home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/access.log combined

    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA/appA/static/

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess appA user=www-data group=www-data \
        python-path=/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ \
        home=/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA/
    WSGIProcessGroup appA
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA.wsgi

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server>
        WSGIProcessGroup appA
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName appB.com
    ServerAlias www.appB.com
    ServerAdmin admin@appB.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/appB
    ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/error.log
    CustomLog /home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/access.log combined

    Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/appB/appB/static/

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIDaemonProcess appB user=www-data group=www-data \
        python-path=/home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ \
        home=/home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/appB/
    WSGIProcessGroup appB
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/appB.wsgi

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server>
        WSGIProcessGroup appB
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Contents of `appA.wsgi`

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/python-eggs'

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA/development.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

Contents of `appB.wsgi`

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/python-eggs'

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
ini_path = '/home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/appB/development.ini'
setup_logging(ini_path)
application = get_app(ini_path, 'main')
```

I enabled both sites in apache and realize that when accessing appA, the python scripts in appB's directory is loaded instead. I confirmed this by adding a `print` statement in the `__init__.py` of both apps and the text for appB is printed even when I try to access appA.

I then disabled appB by `$ sudo a2dissite appB`. appB.com fails to load, but appA.com is still loading appB's codes...

I added the following to **appB** `__init__.py` (Note: NOT **appA**)

```
print sys.path[0]
print os.getcwd()
```

the outputs are

```
/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA
```

which is beyond my comprehension because the output point correctly to appA's directory, yet the `print` are added to appB's `__init__.py` which is located in `/home/ubuntu/appB_virtualenv/server/appB/appB/__init__.py`

Also, I have already disabled appB and the apache settings no longer refer to appB's directory anywhere anymore, so why is appA still loading appB's scripts?!

what am I doing wrong? What settings do I need to change to get appA to load the scripts in its own directory? Thanks

---

Additional checks as suggested by Graham

[Embedded or Daemon Mode](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode)

- Daemon mode: `mod_wsgi.process_group = 'appA'`

[Sub Interpreter Being Used](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Sub_Interpreter_Being_Used)

- Main Interpreter: `mod_wsgi.application_group = ''`

[Request Environment](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment)

- `PATH_TRANSLATED: '/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA.wsgi/'`
- `SERVER_NAME: 'appA.com'`
- `SCRIPT_FILENAME: '/home/ubuntu/appA_virtualenv/appA-server/appA.wsgi'`
- `mod_wsgi.application_group: ''`
- `mod_wsgi.process_group: 'appA'`
- `mod_wsgi.version: (3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing looks an issue on first glance.

Use:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Sub_Interpreter_Being_Used

to confirm what process and application group they are each executing in.

Use:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment

to see what SERVER_NAME is set to for each in requests.

Edit your question with the results.

---

UPDATE 1

Where there are two VirtualHost's in the Apache configuration, one cause of requests always ending up at the first VirtualHost and never reaching the second is because NameVirtualHost directive isn't being specified for the port the VirtualHost's are listening on. Normally on Linux this isn't a problem though for port 80 as it would be on by default.

The other reason it can occur is because the host name used in the URL doesn't actually match either the ServerName or ServerAlias in the desired VirtualHost. When this happens Apache will fallback to directing the URL to the first VirtualHost it found when the Apache configuration file was read. To catch when this is occurring, it is generally a good idea to declare a default VirtualHost which is read first and which denies all access. At least this way a request will not end up at the wrong VirtualHost and will be blocked.

For details of this issue with it falling back to the first read VirtualHost, see discussion in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Try defining the default VirtualHost and see whether this issue of it falling back to the first VirtualHost is the issue. Then you can workout what is the issue with the Apache configuration which is causing that to occur.

Comment: I have added the results to the end of the question. Many thanks for help